# multiple loop inside single for statement using cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures, cursor

I have 2 cursors inside my procedure for which i want to use single for loop because using this i want to loop 2 variable inside single select query. The two variable has 2 different values which is used inside single select query. These 2 values are coming from `KPI_DEFINITION` table which gives me timestamp which i want to compare in my select query for data extraction. The first column `KPI_FREQUENCY` has value for example 30 and `KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT` column has value MINUTE. So if we combine these 2 column we will get `30 MINUTE` and there is another combined column value which is `50 MINUTE` and there might be more. So thats why i want to put this inside loop and compare in my select query with the `start_date` field value.But dont know how to do that. I simply use 2 cursors to take this 2 column and trying to loop it inside single for loop but dont know how to do that.There are might be another solution for this if i dont want to use two cursors but did not find a way.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "EXT_TEST" AS 

LAST_WF_ID Number := 0;
LAST_UNIT NUMBER:=10;
LAST_UNIT_VAL VARCHAR2(20);

CURSOR KPI_FREQUENCY_CUR IS
Select KPI_FREQUENCY INTO LAST_UNIT from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE 
EVENT_ID = 10028;

CURSOR KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT_CUR IS
Select KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT INTO LAST_UNIT_VAL from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE 
EVENT_ID = 10028;

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST_UNIT - ' || LAST_UNIT);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST_UNIT_VAL - ' || LAST_UNIT_VAL);

select MIN(ID) INTO LAST_WF_ID from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL where start_date > sysdate - numtodsinterval(LAST_UNIT,LAST_UNIT_VAL);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST_WF_ID - ' || LAST_WF_ID);

END EXT_TEST;

Sample data from KPI_DEFINITION table:

KPI_DEF_ID  KPI_FREQUENCY KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT  EVENT_ID
1000136     30            MINUTE                10028   
1000137     50            MINUTE                10028
```

Comment: Why not join those tables ?  It sounds like you have a 1 to 1 relationship .. with a single KPI_FREQUENCY matching up with a single KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT ?? Can you post some sample data you have ? and what you expect to see as output ?

Comment: hmm, just noticed, that "1 to 1" relationship I mentioned is same table! O.o  this looks like you're going about things all wrong .. working on a rewrite .. post some sample data, please.

Comment: Actually these two columns are inside KPI_DEFINITION table so i think its not possible to join it right ? And i already given sample values in this 2 column which is 30 MINUTE. The KPI_FREQUENCY comtain value 30 and KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT contain value MINUTE. So i want to take this as combined input and used in my select query so as to compare with start_date in order to perform data extraction. So i will get for example the data for 30 MINUTE from the start_date.

Comment: no need to join since they are same table .. no need for 2 cursors, either ;) **Post some sample data please.**

Comment: I didn't get what sample data you need ? Can you please tell me what data you need ?

Comment: What does your data look like?  Provide 4-8 rows of some example data that exists in those tables ...

Comment: Ok 1 min i will provide you the sample data

Comment: Please check in question about the sample data

Comment: What about the other table: WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL ??

Comment: Actually its a huge table with number of fields so i cant put it here and i think we dont need it to show here right ? My select query is working fine with the 30 MINUTE timestamp but as we have more than one timestamp i have to loop it right ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this procedure? What are you going to do with the results of your query? It may well be that a loop is totally unnecessary, and that you can do everything in a single sql statement (eg. `insert into ... select ...` if you're going to be inserting the results somewhere)

Comment: @Rahul .. you don't need to show the entire table .. but we need to see 4-8 rows, and show the start_date and ID columsn only .. since those are all you use here ... hence they are all we care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending seeing what data your actually on .. I'd suggest trying something a lot simpler ... such as this:

```
  select r.kpi_frequency, r.kpi_freq_time_unit, min(f.id) 
    from rator_monitoring_configuration.kpi_definition   r,
         wf_workflow@fonic_retail    f
   where r.event_id = 10028
     and f.start_date > sysdate - numtodsinterval ( r.kpi_frequency, r.kpi_freq_time_unit );
   group by r.kpi_frequency, r.kpi_freq_time_unit
   order by r.kpi_frequency, r.kpi_freq_time_unit;
```

Comment: Can you please check the sample data in question. Without loop will it work ?

Comment: Can *you* please try the query and see how it runs with YOUR data ? And post results if error, or explain what results you expect ?

Comment: Hello this query works perfectly and giving the result what i want :) thank you and now no need to write cursor or loop.

Comment: Lesson learned: Never do in PL/SQL what you can do in pure SQL  ;) always look for a pure SQL solution if you can. It'll be simpler, easier and perform better in the long run.  Good luck!